# WebSocket exception while attempt to hub connect

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I completely confused in signalR. I tried to repeat [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy) example, but every time did catch Websocket exception. My Hub class looks like :

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public void NewContosoChatMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addContosoChatMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

and client JS code like :

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function (name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
});
connection.start().done(function () {
    $('#sendButton').click(function () {
        contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', $('#userInput').val(), $('#messageInput').val());
        $('#messageInput').val('').focus();
    });
});
```

I use Windows 10 and iis v10.0.1734.
Unfortunately, whatever I do, every time failed to connect to server hub.
Exceptions :

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ut7J.png)

I have no idea, how to solve this issue. Help, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting) in the same documentation you are using under troubleshooting. You should start with the documentation and go from there.

"301 Moved Permanently" or "302 Moved Temporarily" error
This error may be seen if the project contains a folder called SignalR, which will interfere with the automatically-created proxy. To avoid this error, do not use a folder called SignalR in your application, or turn automatic proxy generation off. See The Generated Proxy and what it does for you for more details.